# Plotting from the celebrated Euler's formula

Tags: plotting, complex

> ```
> ContourPlot[ x^(I*y) == -1, { x, 1, 3}, {y, 1, 3}]
> ```

A newbie's query..The most famous equation should ( methinks) yield a lot of points other than the real pair $(e,\pi);$ in the above, there is however no ContourPlot.

There is nothing unique about this point, it ought to belong to a set. Or do $(x,y)$ turn out to be complex numbers in general?

How to manipulate or otherwise operate in *Mathematica*  to obtain the curve $y=f(x)?$ Or, $ w = f(z) ?$

Thanks for attention to the old/classical query.

EDIT 1/2

Further on to find curve containing $(e,\pi)$ with Nasser's suggestion from comments:

```
ContourPlot[x^(I*y) == -1, {x, 1, 10}, {y, 1, 10}]
monge = Plot3D[
   Re[x^(I*y) + 1] == Im[x^(I*y) + 1], {x, 1, 10}, {y, 1, 10}];
SLICEmonge = 
  SliceContourPlot3D[z^2 - .01, 
   Re[x^(I*y) + 1] == Im[x^(I*y) + 1], {x, 1, 10}, {y, 1, 10}, {z, 
    0, .1}];
plane = ContourPlot3D[z == 0, {x, 1, 10}, {y, 1, 10}, {z, 0, .1}];
Show[{SLICEmonge, plane}, PlotRange -> All]
```

In the ContourPlot we have level curves between $(z=0, z=2)$ approximately.

We are now in a situation to find the new points set that is locus of troughs as center of the blue regions.

[image]
EDIT 3:

Above plot suggested by Simon Woods in comments runs for low arguments.

The following does not however plot beyond x>80:

```
ContourPlot[Arg[-x^(I*y)] == 0, {x, 20, 250}, {y, 1, 60}]
```

Thanks for hints about further needed conditions for a full domain plot.

Comment: Not sure what you looking for. But you could do `ContourPlot[ReIm[x^(I*y) + 1], {x, 1, 3}, {y, 1, 3}]`  and also `Plot3D[ReIm[x^(I*y) + 1], {x, 1, 3}, {y, 1, 3}]` gives 3D. V 12.1 has `ComplexContourPlot` but I have not used it myself.

Comment: You should get the union of curves $x=e^{\frac{(2k+1)\pi}y}$, $k\in\mathbb Z$.

Comment: Not sure what you mean, I plotted for three k values.

Comment: I just mean that $x^{iy}=e^{iy\log(x)}$, so $x^{iy}+1=0$ gives $e^{iy\log(x)}=-1=e^{i(2k+1)\pi}$, hence $y\log(x)=(2k+1)\pi$, hence $\log(x)=\frac{(2k+1)\pi}y$, hence $x=e^{\frac{(2k+1)\pi}y}$

Comment: @Nasser Plotted first as shown; second ContourPlot[ReIm[x^(I*y) + 1 == 0], {x, 1, 10}, {y, 1, 10}]  returns nothing.

Comment: @მამუკაჯიბლაძე Can we get to plot one $ f(x,y)=0?$

Comment: `Plotted first as shown; second ContourPlot[ReIm[x^(I*y) + 1 == 0], {x, 1, 10}, {y, 1, 10}]` try `ContourPlot[ReIm[x^(I*y) + 1], {x, 1, 10}, {y, 1, 10}]` screen shot  ![Mathematica graphics](http://i.stack.imgur.com/7jrrB.png)

Comment: The simplest way to get the plot is probably `ContourPlot[Arg[-x^(I*y)] == 0, {x, 1, 10}, {y, 1, 10}]`

Comment: @ Simon Woods: Indeed. it separates $ x^{i y}+1=0 ,\,x^{i y}-1=0 ,\, $

Comment: @ Simon Woods: However there is no plot beyond $x> 80$ in ContourPlot[Arg[-x^(I*y)] == 0, {x, 20, 250}, {y, 1, 60}].  Can you please help? I tried MaxResolution, higher y values etc., but to no avail.